# Extract numbers enclosed in【 】which are of different length?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, extract

How to change the parameters of my codes to extract the number within【】which are of different length?
I have a df storing numbers in this format 【123】. However, the number in df["News"] is of different length as follws:

df["News"] :

```
【123】text text , 
【1234】text text text , 
【1】text text text...
```

My code  :

```
df['num'] = df['News'].str.extract('(\d{4})')
```

Desired output:

```
123
1234
1
```

Comment: `str.extract('(\d+)')` ?

Comment: Thanks. The code extracted the digits. How to confine the extraction within 【】, because there are other numbers outside the 【】.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo:

```py
import re
s = '''【123】text text , 
【1234】text text text , 
【1】text text text... ，
【abc】text text text 456 text'''

reg = '【(\w+)】'

for i in s.split('\n'):
    r = re.search(reg, i)
#     print(i, r)
    if r:
        print(r.group(1))
```

output

```
123
1234
1
abc
```

Comment: Some entries are like this【abc】text text text 456 text  Therefore, need to confine the search within 【】. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe like that?

Comment: Thanks.  I try to apply on my df and added this code  s = df['News'], there is error " 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'" >. What modification is need, if extraction needed to perform on a df column?

Comment: You can just use the code : df['num'] = df['News'].str.extract('【(\w+)】')，change the reg

Answer (score 1):

Use: `.str.extract('(【\d+】)')`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"News":['【123】text text 123', '【1234】text text text 2344, kkk', '【1】text text text 09ekk']})
df['num'] = df['News'].str.extract('(【\d+】)')
#or
df['num_1'] = df['News'].str.extract('【(\d+)】')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                             News     num num_1
0              【123】text text 123   【123】   123
1  【1234】text text text 2344, kkk  【1234】  1234
2         【1】text text text 09ekk     【1】     1
```

Comment: Some entries are like this【abc】text text text 456 text  Therefore, need to confine the search within 【】. How to do it? Thanks.